# Is foreach the only way to consume a BlockingCollection<T> in C#?

Tags: .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, blockingcollection

I'm starting to work with TPL right now. I have seen a simple version of the producer/consumer model utilizing TPL in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1FbKiHYHcw#t=1441s).

Here is the problem:

The following code:

```
BlockingCollection<Double> bc = new BlockingCollection<Double>(100);
IEnumerable<Double> d = bc.GetConsumingEnumerable();
```

returns an `IEnumerable<Double>` which can be iterated (and automatically consumed) using a foreach:

```
foreach (var item in d)
{
    // do anything with item
    // in the end of this foreach,
    // will there be any items left in d or bc? Why?
}
```

My questions are:

1. if I get the `IEnumerator<Double> dEnum = d.GetEnumerator()` from `d` (to iterate over `d` with a `while` loop, for instance) would the `d.MoveNext()` consume the list as well? (My answer: I don't think so, because the the `dEnum` is not *linked* with `d`, if you know what I mean. So it would consume `dEnum`, but not `d`, nor even `bc`)
2. May I loop through `bc` (or `d`) in a way other than the `foreach` loop, consuming the items? (the `while` cycles much faster than the `foreach` loop and I'm worried with performance issues for scientific computation problems)
3. What does exactly *consume* mean in the `BlockingCollection<T>` type?

E.g., code:

```
IEnumerator<Double> dEnum = d.GetEnumerator();
while (dEnum.MoveNext())
{
    // do the same with dEnum.Current as
    // I would with item in the foreach above...
}
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Why do you think `foreach` would have performance issues?

Comment: Well, I've done some really dummy tests (like iterating through an array with millions elements and performing exactly the same conditional checking over each item of the array) and measured the time it took for `while`, for `for` and for `foreach` to finish the task... In the, the `while` was considerably faster...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I get the `IEnumerator<Double> dEnum = d.GetEnumerator()` from d (to iterate over d with a while loop, for instance) would the d.MoveNext() consume the list as well?

Absolutely. That's all that the `foreach` loop will do anyway.

> May I loop through bc (or d) in a way other than the foreach loop, consuming the items? (the while cycles much faster than the foreach loop and I'm worried with performance issues for scientific computation problems)

If your `while` loop is faster, that suggests you're doing something wrong. They should be exactly the same - except the `foreach` loop will dispose of the iterator too, which you should do...

If you can post a short but complete program demonstrating this discrepancy, we can look at it in more detail.

An alternative is to use [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx) (and similar methods).

> What does exactly consume mean in the BlockingCollection type?

"Remove the next item from the collection" effectively.

Comment: As I responded to the comment by @Reed, I've done some dummy tests and `while` seems faster... At least when dealing with non-parallalel problems...

Comment: @Girardi: Your comment talks about iterating over *arrays*. Have you actually iterated over a `BlockingCollection<T>`? Also, it's *very* easy to get benchmarking like this wrong. That's why I've requested a short but complete program demonstrating the issue - there's no point in going off on a completely different route based on faulty assumptions.

Comment: Well, as I'm a complete ignorant in TPL, I didn't test the `BlockingCollection<T>`. So I may have made faulty assumptions after all...

Comment: @Girardi: As ever - get code working in a simple way first, then measure performance.

Comment: Well, what I meant by *consume* is: does it remove the item from the `BlockingCollection<T>` or just from the `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @Girardi: It removes it from the blocking collection. That's why it's a "consuming enumerable". From the docs for `GetConsumingEnumerable`: "An IEnumerable<T> that removes and returns items from the collection."

Comment: Well, I did the benchmark tests with `foreach` and `while` in `BlockingCollection<T>`, in a parallel scheme and I was surprised to check that `foreach` was 10x faster then `while`!

Comment: @Girardi: Again, you'd have to show actual benchmarking code for that to be validated. `foreach` and the `while` loop really should do basically the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "performance issue" with `foreach`.  Using the enumerator directly is not likely to give you any measurable improvement in performance compared to just using a `foreach` loop directly.

That being said, [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) returns a standard `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can enumerate it any way you choose.  Getting the `IEnumerator<T>` and enumerating through it directly will still work the same way.

Note that, if you don't want to use `GetConsumingEnumerable()`, you could just use [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) directly.  By default, `BlockingCollection<T>` wraps a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, and really just provides a simpler API (`GetConsumingEnumerable()`) to make Producer/Consumer scenarios simpler to write.  Using a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` directly would be closer to using `BlockingCollection<T>` without using the enumerable.

Comment: As I responded to the comment by @Reed, I've done some dummy tests and `while` seems faster... At least when dealing with non-parallalel problems...

Comment: @Girardi Typically, the performance difference of the language construct itself will pale in comparison to any computation being performed.  This is especially true if you're working with something like `BlockingCollection<T>` - the while/for/foreach differences would be microscopic compared to just the overhead of putting items in and out of the collection.  As such, I wouldn't focus on that in your optimization - focus on what makes the cleanest algorithm, so you can find and fix the "real" performance issues (in your code that *uses* the items)

Comment: `BlockingCollection` is more than a simpler API for `ConcurrentQueue` (or other concurrent collections). Its point is that its methods block until an operation can be performed. For example, if you wanted to implement alternative to `BlockingCollection.Take()` using just `ConcurrentQueue`, you would need to manually use some synchronization construct (like `ManualResetEvent`).

Comment: @svick Yes - sorry, I realize my wording wasn't perfectly clear there, either.  BC adds the "blocking" portion, including .Take and .GetConsumingEnumerable to the ConcurrentQueue.  If you want the blocking nature, then yes, you'd need that.  If you want that, though, GetConsumingEnumerable is likely the option you'd want anyways.